# Why did SQL Server go into single user mode?

Tags: sql-server

I've had an application that's been running great for several months.  Thankfully I use try/catch blocks in my database calls because this morning I get an email alert from my catch block that said,

> Message:  Login failed for user 'NT
>   AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'. Reason:
>   Server is in single user mode. Only
>   one administrator can connect at this
>   time.
>
> Source:  .Net SqlClient Data Provider
>
> Data: 
>   System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal

So I go and try to access the application, and yep, verified that it doesn't work.

I was able to remote desktop over to the server and log into SQL Server which suddenly "fixed" the issue, but I don't know why this happened.  ("Fixed" as in now the application does it's normal CRUD operations.)

Does anyone know why this might have spontaneously happened?

Also, if I go to database -> properties -> options -> State, I verified that Restrict Access is in "MULTI_USER".

The app is powered by the mighty SQL Server 2005 express. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you check your Windows Event Logs to see if anything happened to the server? Did it reboot after installing any updates?

Comment: Got a crazy system admin that didn't let me know that was going on.  Just checked the event viewer and saw that's exactly what was going on.  Thanks for helping me verify what was going on!

Comment: @Anjisan: so exactly what happened?

Comment: @Sung Meister: According to the Event Viewer (system) on the server, he was applying updates which included stopping/starting SQL Server.  Would have been nice to know ahead of time.  Had no idea he was doing that.  Good thing I used try/catch and error logging.

Comment: This also happened to me when Windows Update was installing a service pack.